# How do I add a second virtual host to an Apache server config?

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, virtualhost, google-domains

I have an Apache server running on an AWS EC2 instance. Currently, one virtual host is running successfully on the server, and I want to add a second virtual host / domain, but I can't figure out how to get it working.

Anonymizing the data, here's the original information I added to `httpd.conf` to get the first virtual host running:

```
<Directory "/var/www/site-1/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/site-1/public"
    ServerName "site-1.com"
    ServerAlias "*.site-1.com"
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =site-1.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.site-1.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I then have the following registed in Google Domains for `site-1` (with a fake IP address):

```
Host name     Type  TTL      Data
site-1.com    A     1 hour   4.184.56.145
*.site-1.com  A     1 hour   4.184.56.145
```

I then used Certbot to add an SSL cert, which added the following line to `httpd.conf` and an ACME challenge to the Google Domains DNS settings:

```
Include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf
```

This is all working fine. I then purchased a second domain (`site-2.com`), and for now, I'm just trying to get the virtual host running with a very simple `index.html` file in the root of the site directory (i.e., `/var/www/site-2`).

For that, I added the following at the very bottom of `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory "/var/www/site-2">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/site-2"
    ServerName "site-2.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

And the following DNS settings were added to Google Domains for `site-2`:

```
Host name     Type  TTL      Data
site-2.com    A     1 hour   4.184.56.145
```

It's been several hours since all these settings were added for `site-2`, and I restarted the Apache server several times with `sudo systemctl restart httpd`. However, when I go to `site-2.com`, I get the following page, which is not the sample `index.html` file I placed under `/var/www/site-2`:

[image]

It's also worth noting that the favicon for `site-2` is actually the favicon for `site-1`. Not sure why. In addition, the directory/file permissions/ownership for `site-2` is the same as for `site-1`.

Can anyone provide any ideas for why this isn't working? For what it's worth, after doing quite a bit of research, I thought I had to add the following line to `httpd.conf`, but doing so and restarting the server doesn't make a difference:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

---

**Edit**: I just figured something out. For whatever reason, `site-2` is pointing to the `var/www/html` directory. If I put a sample `index.html` file into that directory, then it loads correctly when I go to site-2.com. Why is that? Why is the following virtual-host block not working?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/site-2"
    ServerName "site-2.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you actually getting site-1 instead of site-2? Is site-2.com resolvable? If not for testing add it in your testing machine hosts file. According to Apache http docu, put `Listen 80` on top of your configuration.

Comment: No, I don't get `site-1` instead of `site-2` for site-2.com. I get the Apache Test Page shown above when I go to site-2.com. I have a bunch of virtual hosts running on my local machine, and they all work fine. I already have `Listen 80` at the top of the `httpd.conf` file. Thanks for your suggestions, dexter, but not sure if any of that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly don't know what the deal is, but it just started working. Maybe it was a DNS propagation issue (not sure), but the config I listed in my original question started working.